# Find $T(1,2,i)$ where $T$ is normal and the eigenvalues are given

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following question:

> Let $V=\mathbb{C}³$ with canonical inner product and let $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ satisfing the following properties:
>
> i) The only  eigenvalues of $T$ are $i$ and $-i$
>
> ii) $T$ is normal
>
> iii) The eigenvectors of $i$ are $V_i=[(i,1,1),(i,0,1)]$
>
> Then what is $T(1,2,i)$?
>
> The answer should be $(i,2,1),(0,i,2),(-i,2i,1),(1,2,3i)$ or $(1,2i,1)$

I found a eigenvector of $-i$ by finding the orthogonal complement of $V_i$ and then the coordinates of $(1,2,i)$ in the basis of eigenvectors and then just use the matrix of $T$ in the diagonalized form and take the appropiated change of basis... but I didn't used that $T$ is normal and the result isn't right.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: There's no reason the eigenvector  for $-i$ should be orthogonal to the eigenvectors for $i$ if $T$ is not normal...

Comment: But $V=V_i \oplus V_i ^{\perp} $ and also $V=V_i\oplus V_{-i}$... then $V_{-i}=V_i^{\perp}$, don't?

Comment: In a word, no. In general, a subspace doesn’t have a unique complement. Consider the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2$ vs. the basis $\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$: the spans of $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$ are both complements of the span of $(1,0)$.

Comment: Not unless $T$ is normal,no.